# a simpler sql query

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a the following tables

- students(sid, sname, age)
- course(cid, cname, duration)
- enroll(sid, cid, date)

To find all sid's who had taken the courses which sid = 1 has taken.

```
select sid from enroll where cid in (select cid from enroll where sid=1) 
group by sid having count(*)=(select count(*) from enroll where sid=1) 
minus (select sid from student where sid=1);
```

1. What does the first count(*) refers to?
2. Is there a simpler version of the query?

Comment: `COUNT(*)` means count all rows.

Comment: which rows? the result of `select cid from enroll where sid=1`?

Comment: In your case count(*) is checking sids with enrolled course counts equal to sid =1 enrolled count.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first `COUNT(*)` refers to the count of the rows belonging to a particular `sid`.

Reformatted:

```
SELECT sid
  FROM enroll
 WHERE cid IN (SELECT cid FROM enroll WHERE sid=1) 
 GROUP by sid
HAVING COUNT(*) = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM enroll WHERE sid=1) 
MINUS (SELECT sid FROM student WHERE sid=1);
```

You can certainly avoid the MINUS by using:

```
SELECT sid
  FROM enroll
 WHERE cid IN (SELECT cid FROM enroll WHERE sid=1)
   AND sid != 1
 GROUP by sid
HAVING COUNT(*) = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM enroll WHERE sid=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT s.sid
FROM student s, enroll e
WHERE s.sid = e.sid
AND e.cid IN (SELECT cid FROM course WHERE sid=1)
AND s.sid <> 1
```

Comment: (a) Please do not use the old (pre-1992) notation using a comma separated list of table names in the FROM clause; use the explicit JOIN notation.  (b) That query selects the students that have at least one course in common with `sid=1`, rather than the students who study every course that `sid=1` studies (and possibly some extra ones).  The original query is asking for the students who study all the same courses as `sid=1`.